# multiple file uploads by invoking shell script

Tags: java, sftp

I have a framework using Core java and Spring 2.5 which invokes some sftp script in unix environment to upload the files to destination server. As of now, it supports only 1 file upload per invocation. I am in charge of enhancing the framework so that it supports multiple file upload. However for multiple files to be sftped, if for some reason , the script fails after sftping less number of files then the next invocation of the program should only try to sftp the remaining files (as an added feature rather than retrying all the files). For ex. assuming that on the first invocation, the program is supposed to sftp 5 files and it failed after sftping 2 files then there should be an option to sftp only the remaining 3 files in the next invocation.  As a possible solution, I have multiple options like updating some cache entries or updating db tables but that is not allowed as a solution (and I have not spend much time arguing why as of now). I can think of another solution - writing to a file , the name of the files which were successfully sftped and proceed with the remaining files. However this seems to be a more crude kind of solution and I am thinking of a better solution which should be generic enough. Can you please advice on some better design for this situation? Please note that the destination server is not sending any information back to the source server for all this sftp.

Regards,
Ramakant

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried raising an exception which contains the files that did not sftp correcty?

The exception class could look something like this:

```
import java.io.File;

public class SFTPBulkFailedTransportException extends RuntimeException {

    public SFTPBulkFailedTransportException(File[] untransmittedFiles){
        setUntransmittedFiles(untransmittedFiles);
    }

    public File[] getUntransmittedFiles() {
        return this.untransmittedFiles;
    }

    private void setUntransmittedFiles(File[] untransmittedFiles) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.untransmittedFiles = untransmittedFiles;
    }

    private File[] untransmittedFiles;

}
```

If you throw this exception with all the files that were not transmitted, you have access to them if you catch this exception. This exception would be thrown in the method that transmits the files in bulk.

If you put it all together:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

File[] filesToSend; // all files to send

 while(filesToSend.length != 0){

        try{
            sendbulk(filesToSend);
        }catch(SFTPBulkFailedTransportException exception){
            // assign failed files to filesToSend
            // because of the while loop, sendbulk is invoked again
            filesToSend = exception.getUntransmittedFiles();
    }
}


public void sendbulk(File[] filesToSend) throws SFTPBulkFailedTransportException{

    List<File> unsuccesfullFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    for(File file : filesToSend){
        try{
            sendSingle(file);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException exception){
            unsuccesfullFiles.add(file);
        }
    }

    if(!unsuccesfullFiles.isEmpty()){
        throw new SFTPBulkFailedTransportException( (File[]) unsuccesfullFiles.toArray());
    }
}

public void sendSingle(File file) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    // I am not sure if this is the right way to execute a command for your situation, but
    // you can probably check the exit status of the sftp command (0 means successful)
    String command = "REPLACE WITH SFTP COMMAND";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // if sftp failed, throw exception
    if(child.exitValue() != 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ENTER REASON OF FAILURE HERE");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: but how do I know which files were not successfully transmitted in the first run. If I understand correctly, the above code will report the files which were not sftped but when I reinvoke the program second time, I want to transmit only the unsuccessful files from the first run.

Comment: As for the files that were not send, you get them from the exception. I will update my answer to illustrate how this is done. But i don't know how to see if sftp worked, how do you invoke it for a single file?

Comment: I invoke one shell script through the program. some thing like "sftp <args>" . As per the framework, the way the program will work is - invoke the same script multiple times but each time with different file. The return status from the script will be 0 if the file has been successfully transmitted. I am trying to understand how do I know which files to transmit again in the second run (and hence am thinking that I need to store the information somewhere - database /Cache/Files etc)

Comment: I updated my answer with the "sendSingle" method and "sendBulk" method. In sendBulk, a list is created with all the files that cannot be send. Do you prefer to work with Arrays or with Lists? If you prefer lists, I will replace all the arrays in the example.

Comment: I got a good answer to this topic at the following link - http://www.coderanch.com/t/593735/java/java/Design-suggestion